# two inversly correlated indepent variables...how to combine?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I have a few instances where two independent variables are almost perfectly correlated inversely

usually in such an instance i would remove one
in this instance the two variables each comprise:

```
Variable A: 50% zero values, rest a normalish distribution separate to the zeros;
Variable B: same as A
```

the zeros in A correspond to non zeros in B and vice versa

originally i planned to remove one but i would loose the descriptive power of the non zero values of one of the variables.. if i dropped Var B i would effectively be putting its **distributed** non zero values into the 0 value of Var A.

What is the correct way to proceed?
I could of course run models on each but i have more than one instance of this

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, A=0 iff B!= 0 and vice versa? In such case, even perfect correlation might result in information loss if you combine these variables, because you lose the information whether you measure A or B (if that is a relevant distinction). [You could create a variable C = -A if B=0 and B otherwise, then you could add a dummy variable specifying if you measured A or B.]

Comment: Yes that is correct, if A=0 then B!=0 and vice versa. Yes that was my thought and problem, that I would loos information by dropping a variable. So the variable C would have mean ~ 0? (A values being negative but otherwise unchanged and B values being positive all contained in a new variable)

Comment: You have several options here that depend on the interpretation/theory of the variables A and B. If they basically measure the same thing (but are almost perfectly negatively correlated), then C should probably be -A|B or -B|A. If you construct a dummy variable D that keeps track of whether A or B was measured, you could also include interaction terms. That however would be equivalent to using A and B. So I suggest you provide some information on what A, B are and what kind of analysis you perform.

Comment: In this case A and B are effectively ingredients, either A or B will be used. they are not perfectly negatively correlated as these are the sorts of values i might see - 0A-20B, 0A-18B, 17A-0B - I am trying to find if any variables in independant variables make a affect my dependant variable..AND how. This is why i do not want to use just one variable. B may be significant only at its higher values. therefore compressing its information to the 0 in A (by removing B completely) would loose this

Comment: And why do you want to replace A and B by a combination of the two?

Comment: They are very higly correlated, and also colinear. I get very high VIF scores including them both ~20 in this case